# Access token in KeyChain returning nil in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I am facing a problem in KeyChain access, I am saving password and AccessToken in KeyChain but on login page code is working fine while goto to the next controller I am fetching access token but it returns nil.
I am using a wrapper class.
Saving data in Swift class and code is

```
self.MyKeychainWrapper.mySetObject((((responseDict?.object(forKey: "Response") as AnyObject).object(forKey: "ResponseData")! as AnyObject).object(forKey: "AccessToken")), forKey: kSecAttrTokenID)
```

retrive in same class

`let token = self.MyKeychainWrapper.myObject(forKey: kSecAttrTokenID) as? String`

and in next class i.e obj c class

`NSString *token = [MykeyChainWrapper myObjectForKey:(id)kSecAttrTokenID];`

But returing nil

I checked but not found any solution.

Thanks

Comment: How did you implement the MyKeyChainWrapper class?

Comment: I added KeyChainWrapper.h/.m file into my project provided by apple. MyKeyChainWrapper is the object of KeyChainWrapper class.